# How to make div bigger and change it's content on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a div to become bigger ("covering" area of other divs) and change it's content on hover.

Here is a code snippet showing how my page currently looks like:

```css
.page__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "left-sidebar first-tile second-tile right-sidebar"
                       "left-sidebar third-tile fourth-tile right-sidebar";
  grid-template-columns: 15% 35% 35% 15%;
}

.page__sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.page__sidebar--left {
  grid-area: left-sidebar;
}

.page__sidebar--right {
  grid-area: right-sidebar;
}

.page__tile {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.page__tile--first {
  grid-area: first-tile;
  background-color: white;
}

.page__tile--second {
  grid-area: second-tile;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.page__tile--third {
  grid-area: third-tile;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.page__tile--fourth {
  grid-area: fourth-tile;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="page__container">
  <aside class="page__sidebar page__sidebar--left">
    <span>Sidebar</span>
  </aside>

  <div class="page__tile page__tile--first">
    <span>Components</span>
  </div>

  <div class="page__tile page__tile--second">
    <span>Peripherals</span>
  </div>

  <aside class="page__sidebar page__sidebar--right">
    <span>Sidebar</span>
  </aside>

  <div class="page__tile page__tile--third">
    <span>Laptops</span>
  </div>

  <div class="page__tile page__tile--fourth">
    <span>Accessories</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is how I want it to look like when I hover over the first tile (*components)*.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxxIN.png)

I don't know whether it is possible to do using *grids* or no so I am open to various suggestions about potential changes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JavaScript for this. You can't possibly use grids, grids are useful only for layouts. The closest thing we have to a parent selector in CSS is `:focus-within` pseudo element.

[:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

Answer (score 0):

For changing the size, you can use `scale` command in CSS; more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/scale-on-hover-with-webkit-transition/).You could also use the `z-index` command in order to a div appear in front of other.
 However, I think that this kind of animation is a lot better to do using *javascript*. There are a lot of tutorials on youtube that cover javascript animations like this.